# path of EJB class in lookup function on javaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to inject the content of EJB class to object variable with lookup function but not found the path. Following is my cod in javaEE:

```
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("this is the flight details:.....");
 try{
     Context context = new InitialContext();
     Object ob = context.lookup("java:global/ejb1/SourcePackage/FlightService!com.airline.service.FlightService");
     fs = (FlightService)ob;
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     out.println("not found path");
 }
```

and my structure of project is :

[image]

Comment: Why are you using lookup? Your project seems to be EJB3.1 lite where all of that archaic (and hard) stuff isn't needed?

Comment: I have an amatory in javaEE and don't know what function used for this goal! I see this code in a tutorial

Comment: and when i use @EJB annotation i receive NullPointerException Error and not work annotation

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think is better to understand what wrong with annotation, cause injecting bean is simpler and controls by container not you. Lookup is a choice only when you are tryin to get access to ejb from another jvm.

Secondly your path is wrong. You use `module-name` instead of `app-name` and Source package is a IDE specific thing. Path in JNDI is based on built jar file.
As described in [EJB specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html) global name creates by following pattern

`java:global[/<app-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>[!<fully-qualified-interface-name>]`

where in your case

1. `app-name` normally ear name
2. `module-name` normally EJB jar name (in
   your case ejb1)
3. `bean-name` is simple name of class with annotation
   Stateless, Statefull, Singleton.
4. `interface name` is canonical name of implemented interface